# removechild also removing container ? as3

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild, addchild

I'm trying to removeChild multiple mc from a container.  Why is the container also being removed ?

```
///breadcrumbs
        var randomMc:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);
        var mc:MovieClip =  new myArray[randomMc];
        MapHolder.addChild(mc);

         mc.x = MapHolder.Star.x;
         mc.y = MapHolder.Star.y;





/// remove breadcrumbs  ///
function removeAllChildren(MapHolder:DisplayObjectContainer) 
{
    while(MapHolder.numChildren > 0)
    {
        MapHolder.removeChild(MapHolder.getChildAt(0));
    }
}
//////
```

I think I solved my question.... Since the child is in the container...  it need to be index 1  ?

```
function removeAllChildren(DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    while(MapHolder.numChildren > 1) {
        MapHolder.removeChildAt(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not removing the MapHolder, based on what code we can see. If it's being removed, it's being done elsewhere or you are not correctly understanding something fundamental that leads you to believe it's been removed. Hard to tell by just looking at this code and given your current description of the issue. As the current answer points out, you are not assigning clips to `mc` correctly, so it's possible there are more similar errors elsewhere as well.

Comment: i tried to take that "new" out of the new myArray[randomMc];   but it causes error.  I'm laying down random clips mc1 or mc2.   i simply want to remove all the breadcrumbs when i call removeAllChildren(MapHolder);

Comment: I can't help you if you assume my first comment is not asking for more than what we see in this question. Your comment on the answer confirms my suspicions that there is some phantom code that you don't think is an issue... yet it is. Sorry, can't help you.

Comment: For example.. here's a mystery needing to be revealed before anyone can help you in regards to the new error after removing the `new` keyword. What is in the array ? Show us the code that fills that array, so we can confirm what is in there as opposed to assuming.

Comment: thats ok.  i solved it .... but here is the code... //// breadcrumbs ///////////
 var myArray:Array = [mc1,mc2]; ///breadcrumbs
        var randomMc:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);
        var mc:MovieClip =  new myArray[randomMc];
        MapHolder.addChild(mc);   //// it was suggested i remove the "new" ... but that resulted in an error.   i solved my original question ass noted above.  thanks

Comment: So let me guess Bob, the problem was that your container was a child of our MapHolder, right ? haha. That is NOT what your question says. If  the code you posted works, it's because the container IS a child of MapHolder. Nobody could solve your problem with the flawed description, we simply trusted what you said to be the case.

Comment: "I'm trying to removeChild multiple mc from a container. Why is the container also being removed ?" Based on your solution whatever you considered your 'container' was the first child on the display list of MapHolder. Therefore... your flawed understanding of what you were doing, made you unable to articulate the proper question.

Answer (score 1):

this line here :

```
var mc:MovieClip =  new myArray[randomMc];
```

you just can't do that you can not make a new element from already existing element you probably mean

```
var mc:MovieClip = myArray[randomMC];
```

cheers

Comment: when I take that "new" out it gives me an error.   I'm simply leaving a trail of random mc1, or mc2.  I think I have a problem with my function call.  Because it is deleting the container mc.  TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mc1$ to flash.display.MovieClip.
 at test_fla::MainTimeline/circleHit()

Comment: that caused an error when i took out "new"  .   I think the problem is when i call the function removeAllChildren(MapHolder);

Comment: Coericion Failed means you that you are trying to assing variable from type A to type B. This means the array is not with MovieClip instances but something else. use the trace(); command to find out lts going on !